# .htaccess - Querystring without index.php

Tags: .htaccess, get, seo, url-rewriting, query-string

I want my url's to look like this: "http://www.example.com/start",
and not like this: "http://www.example.com/index.php/start".
That works fine with this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1
```

On one page i have to work with GET-Parameters, the url should look like this:
"http://www.example.com/artists/picasso", 
and not like this: 
"http://www.example.com/index.php/artists?artist=picasso"
That's also possible with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?/$1
RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)$ /index.php/artists?artist=$1 [L]
```

Now, the problem with this solution is, that all other url's now have to end with a slash.
So it has to look like this: "http://www.example.com/start/",
and not like this: "http://www.example.com/start"

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !artists/
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?/$1
RewriteRule ^artists/(.*)$ /index.php/artists?artist=$1 [L]
```

Mainly, you have a `/$` at the end of your pattern: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?/$1` which means it has to end with a slash in order to match the pattern. Changing it to `(.*?)/?$` makes it optional.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :) This works. But what does "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !artists/" do ?

Comment: @Andri it isn't necessary, but it's to prevent it matching requests like `/artists/`